# md5 php and android not same

Tags: java, android, md5

I am calculating the md5 of a file but getting different results

code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();
String as = null;
try {
    InputStream is=am.open("sdapk.db");
    as=is.toString();
}catch(IOException e) {
    Log.v("Error_E",""+e);
}
String  res = md5(as);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(res);
setContentView(tv);
}
public String md5(String s) { 
try { 
    MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); digest.update(s.getBytes()); byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

 // Create Hex String
 StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
 for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
     hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
return hexString.toString();

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
return "";
}

}
```

php md5 : E959637E4E88FDEC377F0A15A109BB9A

Comment: You can check which is right by using the Linux command line tool `md5sum`.

Comment: i am not using linux. I have to check md5 at runtime when app will start.Above code giving the different result.I checked the md5 in php and from window utility and result is same but above code not giving the same result.

Comment: The problem is the code is not working properly. Check the discussion at the website that the original code is given: [Android Snippets](http://www.androidsnippets.com/create-a-md5-hash-and-dump-as-a-hex-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InputStream.toString()` probably doesn't do what you want it to.  It's not overridden in the normal JDK, so it's basically `Object.toString()`...which will return you a string like `"java.io.InputStream@12345678"`.  Even if Android's stuff did return a string representing the stream's contents, it'd get really weird since you never specify what encoding to use to convert bytes to chars.

You should read the stream in if you want to MD5 it.  Kinda like

```
private static char[] hexDigits = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

public String md5(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    int read = 0;
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1)
    {
        digest.update(bytes, 0, read);
    }

    byte[] messageDigest = digest.digest();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);

    // Oh yeah, this too.  Integer.toHexString doesn't zero-pad, so
    // (for example) 5 becomes "5" rather than "05".
    for (byte b : messageDigest)
    {
        sb.append(hexDigits[(b >> 4) & 0x0f]);
        sb.append(hexDigits[b & 0x0f]);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```