# checking integrity of a file using md5

Tags: java, android, md5, inputstream

I am trying to check the integrity of a database file in asset folder and i am using **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337226/md5-php-and-android-not-same)** code  in android app.

I don't know in it is correct to directly convert InputStream to string

My question is that in this code how to convert the file in assets folder in string.

I tried BufferdReader as

```
  AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();
  String as = null;
InputStream is=null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try {
    is=am.open("sdapk.db");
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

     while ((as=br.readLine())!=null) {
          sb.append(as + "\n");
        }
     is.close();

}catch(IOException e) {
    Log.v("Error_E",""+e);
}
String  res = md5(sb.toString());
```

but no luck

please shed some light on this and guide me in right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: why?? you are giving downvote?????????? if there is any problem in question then tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\n might change the original content resulting in different MD5. Some system use \r for carriage return.
You should use the inputstream directly as following

```
byte[]b=new byte[1024];
while(is.read(b)!=-1){
 //do your magic here with b
}
```

Comment: thanks!! solved it from my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337226/md5-php-and-android-not-same/8338800#8338800